# Best way to simulate movement inside react-native-maps using an android emulator without using Expo?

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, react-native-maps

What is the best way to simulate movement inside react-native-maps using an Android emulator?  I know that you can load a gpx file in the location settings menu.  However that only works with google maps inside the emulator, not a custom app that utilizes react-native-maps.

I'm also aware that it is possible to simulate user movement using the Expo-Location library.

```
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
    const tenMetersWithDegrees = 0.0001;

    const getLocation = increment => {
        return {
            timestamp: 100000,
            coords: {
                speed: 0, 
                heading: 0,
                accuracy: 5,
                altitudeAccuracy: 5,
                altitude: 5,
                longitude: -122.9779983 + increment * tenMetersWithDegrees,
                latitude: 37.5665 + increment * tenMetersWithDegrees,
            }
        }
    }

    let counter = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
        Location.EventEmitter.emit('Expo.locationChanged', {
          watchId: Location._getCurrentWatchI(),
          location: getLocation(count)
        })
        counter++
      }, 1000);
```

Would it be possible to build this same type script using just react native geolocation service?

Answer (score 0):

With android emulator, you can simulate route. Check below screenshot

[image: ```]